# What is the proper way to declare variables in php?

Tags: php

I was using variables in my php file without declaring them. It was working perfect in old version of localhost (i.e vertrigoServ 2.22).

But when I moved to latest version of localhost (i.e xampp 3.2.1), I encountered variables declaration warnings and errors something like this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: att_troops_qty in D:\Installed
>   Programs\htdocs\dashboard\WarLord\PHP_Code\MyAjax.php on line 1247

So I declared all the variables at the top of php file like this:

```
$page = "";
$att_troops_qty = "";
$def_troops_qty = "";
$ca_level = "";
$b_level = "";
$pre_buildings = "";
$created_pre_b = "";
$building_id = "";
$building_loc = "";
$ca_1_b_loc = "";
$ca_1_b_level = "";
$ca_2_b_loc = "";
$ca_2_b_level = "";
```

It solved the problem But I have confusion that this is not the proper way to declare variables.

Is there some more better way for variables declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How you are declaring is perfectly alright and proper way.

```
$test = "";

or

$test = null;
```

these both are proper ways for declaring empty variables.
for more info please visit http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare variables before echoing them out. An example is here:

```
<?php
    $var = "test";
    echo $var; // it will echo out test
?>
```

And trying to echo out a variable this way will generate an error:

```
<?php
    echo $var; // it will generate error
    $var = "test";
?>
```

In addition, you can declare variables in another file and can include that file to echo out the variable somewhere. Remember to include the file first and then call it.

Example **vars.php**:

```
<?php
    // define vars
    $var1 = "Test 1";
    $var2 = "Test 2";
?>
```

Now in another file, **`include vars.php`** first and then call the variable:

```
<?php
    require_once"vars.php";
    echo $var1;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use undeclared variables but
you can declare them on the go.

Inside functions you can do something like that:

```
function abc() {
    return $newVar or null; // without variable declaration
}
```

If $newVar is not declared before function will return null;

Or better way:

```
function abc($newVar = null) {
    return $newVar; // with variable declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check whether the variable is declare or not, is to use the **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function, which checks whether the variable is **set**  or not like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($a)){
       // execute when $a is set ( already declare ) or have some value
    }
    else {
      // execute when $a not set
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables in php as

```
<?php
   $test = "xyz" //for String datatype
   $test1 = 10 //for integer datatype
?>
```

Name of a variable declared must be alphanumeric and you don't need to specify the type.